# Display Problems on VMware

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, vmware, vmware-player

The login screen is as it should be but after Iogin, desktop appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BDBF.jpg). Actually, I guess the program icons are there since I am able to click to a black region on the left and drag it, seeing a little square shaped bad image coming along with the cursor. My version is 14.04.2. What might be the problem?